# How to send new information to STOPped process

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, signals, node.js

Say I have a long-running process, and I stop and restart it using:

```
kill -STOP <pid>
kill -CONT <pid>
```

is there a consistent way to alter the running process, either environment variables or some memory location?

something like this:

```
    kill -STOP <pid>

    change_process <pid> --new 'value'

    kill -CONT <pid>
```

obviously that's a completely bogus api, but hopefully you get the idea

Answer (score 1):

No. Stopped process is stopped.

The traditional way to change settings of the running process is to teach the application to control the state of its config file. Either have inotify watch, or just check modification timestamp periodically. Either way, once the application sees that its config file was modified - reread it.

Another way is to catch a signal which will force a restart or just reconfigure. For example, Apache on SIGHUP does a soft restart - kills all subprocesses and restart main process with rereading config files.
This approach is more convenient if you have a multi-file config. It is difficult to put a watcher on each included sub-config file.

Environment variables are little different - they are copied into the processes memory at the start of the application, and it is impossible to reach them from outside of the process. You can ask the process to change its own environment, you can give this environment to a child process (which can change it too). But you cannot change them from outside.

STOP-CONT in this case could in theory help, if you want to pause the application, do a lot of changes to config and then restart with rereading config. But they (SIGSTOP-SIGCONT) can just give you more time for making changes to config. It could be easier just stop application completely.

Comment: It's a long-story, but Node.js by design has no interrupt/pre-emption. So if you are running synchronous code, i/o won't have a chance to interrupt that synchronous code until the sync code finishes. So if you have a `while(true)` loop that runs forever, there is no way to interrupt it, except a SIGINT or SIGKILL, but even then we can't get information into the runtime, the signal seems to be at OS layer to stop the process. So I am looking for some backdoor mechanism to change memory in the process somehow...some trick. Otherwise, I have to resort to polling from within the sync code.

Comment: Then do as I described. Read settings from config.txt, once a minute check its modification time, and reread when necessary. Works in any environment where you can check file's stats or version.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to avoid high rates of polling, or 59 second delays in updates, etc..but with node.js in this case since there are no interrupts, only way is to use asynchronous recursion, using constructs like `async/await` or `process.nextTick()`; a synchronous `while(true)` loop will never yield to I/O while it runs in node. OP was sort of my last attempt at an alternative.